# Wordpress + polylang как формировать однотипные URL в разных языках

Tags: php, wordpress, url, polylang

Как на WordPress с мультиязычным плагином Polylang сделать так, чтобы на втором языке линки формировались точно также как и на основном, с добавкой поддомена.

Например основной линк в английской локализации: name.com/about, при переключении на второй язык линк должен быть: name.com/ru/about.

Сейчас при переключении формируется такой линк: name.com/ru/kompaniya, т.е. спроисходит транслитерация.

Comment: Во-первых, непонятно, что у вас там установлено. Если траслитерация, то, скорее всего, наш cyr2lat. Но дело не в этом. Если вы руками измените kompaniya на about, то получите что-то вроде about-1. Чтобы сделать ярлыки одинаковыми на разных языках, вам нужен Polylang Pro.

Comment: Да, установлен Cyr-To-Lat.

Comment: Хорошо. Но к делу это не относится ))

Comment: А "хвост" урла тоже может быть одинаковым? Или он должен отличаться от основного.
Например: на основном языке:
name.com/services/razresh-docs/certification-state/sertifikacija-produkcii-sertifikat-sootvetstviya-156/

на дополнительном:
name.com/ru/services/razresh-docs/certification-state/sertifikacija-produkcii-sertifikat-sootvetstviya-156/

Comment: Я ответил - да. Нужен Pro.

Comment: Большое спасибо

Answer (score 0):

С помощью Polylang Pro сделал так, чтобы URL были одинаковыми на разных языках. Все заработало. Спасибо KAGG Design.

Comment: не нужно в ответах задавать новый вопрос. Если у вас возникают новые вопросы, то вы либо дополняйте свой текущий вопрос, либо создавайте новую тему